# MVC3 Custom view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webforms

I have a custom View Engine that derives from WebFormViewEngine. There's a lot of stuff going on in here, mostly caching. I want to be able to use WebFormViewEngine AND RazorViewEngine at the same time, is this possible? Ideally I'd like to do;

`ViewEngines.Add(new MyViewEngine<WebFormsViewEngine>());`
`ViewEngines.Add(new MyViewEngine<RazorViewEngine>());`

if a .ascx/.aspx/.master file exists then use WebForms, otherwise use Razor is a .cshtml file exists.

EDIT: I should of worded my question better. As my custom view engine derives from WebFormViewEngine it obviously uses WebForms, I can't derive from two classes. I can derive from RazorViewEngine but then I'll loose WebForms. I can duplicate my code entirely, derive from RazorViewEngine and edit the views file extensions, etc. but as I said I've got a lot of custom code in my view engine and would be duplicating hundreds of lines.

WebFormViewEngine and RazorViewEngine derive from BuildManagerViewEngine which in turn implements IViewEngine. The problem with that is I have to implement methods CreatePartialView() and CreateView() but how would I know what to return (WebForms/Razor?) using generics?

Comment: I've edited my question, I don't think I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up with creating an abstract class: `public abstract class MyViewEngine : BuildManagerViewEngine, IViewEngine { }` and then implement/override the `FindView` and `FindPartialView` methods (which had my caching code in). I had an abstract method `public abstract void SetSearchPaths();` that was called in my `ctor`.

I then created another class that derived from `MyViewEngine` for WebForms specifically:

```
public class MyViewEngineWebForms : MyViewEngine
{
    public override void SetSearchPaths()
    {
        base.MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Skins/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master", "~/Skins/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master" };
        base.ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Skins/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx", "~/Skins/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx", "~/Skins/Shared/Views/{0}.aspx" };
        base.PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Skins/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx", "~/Skins/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx", "~/Skins/Shared/PartialViews/{0}.ascx" };
        base.FileExtensions = new string[] { "aspx", "ascx", "master" };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new WebFormView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, base.ViewPageActivator);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        return new WebFormView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, base.ViewPageActivator);
    }
}
```

and did exactly the same for Razor but change the file extensions to .cshtml/.vbhtml and change `WebFormView` to `RazorView`. Add them to the `ViewEngine` collection:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new SeeTicketsWebFormsViewEngine());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new SeeTicketsRazorViewEngine());
```

and now they work perfectly again, side by side with all of my custom caching logic.

Answer (score 2):

It's **possible, but not recommended** way because it introduces some mess into your project. You can read good article on it: [Using Multiple View Engines](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/07/29/asp-net-mvc-3-using-multiple-view-engines-in-same-project.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter.

By default, MVC3 includes both the `WebFormsViewEngine` and the `RazorViewEngine`, these are both registered automatically. I believe they are ordered as `WebFormsViewEngine` and then `RazorViewEngine` also, which means the web forms view will be checked first. If it finds a view, it will use it. If it cannot, it will use the next view engine, which is the Razor view engine.

Have you tried removing your custom view engine and just leaving the default configuration?

Comment: Yes, and it does work. I need the custom view engine though as it has a lot of caching of views going on.

Comment: Does the existing caching in the standard view engines not work for you? I think you could go one of two ways. Either build a composite view engine which checks the `WebFormsViewEngine` and then the `RazorViewEngine` in that order, or build a composite view engine that performs the operations of both view engines, but returns a specific `IView` depending on the file extension of the chosen view (override `CreateView`, `CreatePartialView` or your `VirtualPathProviderViewEngine`). The latter is more tricky, because you need to logical separate the view locating logic depending on the targe type.